# Controlar salto de pagina si el div se corta

Tags: html, css, print

Estoy imprimiendo un contenido html y quiero que si mi div con clase pedido2 se corta salte de pagina.

para ello utilizo el siguiente css

```
div.pedido2{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
div{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Si comento el css de div no funciona el div.pedido2 porque dentro de mi div.pedido2 hay mas div dentro de el pero yo solo quiero hacerlo con mi div.pedido2.

Seria algo asi.

```
<div class="pedido2">
    <div class="diaservicio">
       2020-09-01
    </div>
    <div class="pedido" style="width:48%;float:left;padding:5px">
          <p><strong>2407 JOSE</strong></p>
          <p>Garbanzos con chorizo</p><p>Fruta</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pedido" style="width:48%;float:left;padding:5px">
          <p><strong>2407 JUAN</strong></p>
          <p>Biscotes/picos</p></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Esto seria asi cada dia tiene un pedido2 con sus diferentes pedidos y quiero que no se me corte en mitad de la hoja cuando lo imprimo utilizando print()

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro el esquema de la página, ¿puedes poner el HTML afectado?

Comment: La regla aplicada a .pedido2 debería aplicar a todo su interior, tenga hijos o no. ¿Se te corta al imprimir?

Comment: Si por ejemplo se me queda la fecha en una hoja y el pedido en otra

Comment: No sé si influye, pero prueba a poner las reglas dentro de `@media print {...}` para decir expícitamente que se han de aplicar a la hora de imprimir

Comment: lo tengo dentro del @media print